How to measure an unknown impedance
I want to experimentally measure input impedance of an RF amplifier that I have previously built for use in the 88-108 MHz range. An LTSpice simulation says that I should have an input impedance of ~20 ohms at my frequencies of interest. I have no clue what the true value is, or might be.
On paper, if I were to calibrate a nanoVNA with the 50 ohm standards they ship with and attempt to measure a potentially non 50-ohm system:

Would S11 measurement results tell me what any hardware would be presented with at the input of my circuit?

Or, would they instead tell me what a 50 ohm antenna fitted to 50 ohm coax line would be presented with at the input of my circuit?




You could inject a known ac current into the input. Then measure the amplitude and phase shift of the voltage drop of the input. Then you can calculate the input impedance.

That's a neat idea. Would probes interfere with accuracy/need to be factored out somehow?

A properly calibrated VNA will measure the impedance attached to the calibrated port (more precisely, it measures S11 from which Z can be calculated).
The accuracy is best for impedance not too far from the reference impedance.
